# Typescript: infer type of property in nested object

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm using graphql and there is `ConnectionType` which has property `pageInfo` and `edges`. In this context, I have to use `pageInfo.hasNextPage` and `pageInfo.endCursor` and `nodes` which is mapped from `edges`. I can use manually like below.

```
const { hasNextPage, endCursor } = pageInfo ?? {};
const nodes = edges.flatMap(edge => edge?.node ?? []) ?? [];
```

Evenry `ConnectionType` has `pageInfo` and `edges` field. Also, `edge` field has `node` field so I can map `node` from `edge` like above code. But, `node` type could be different from each other.

This code is duplicate, so I wanna extract this function as util.

```
interface PageInfo {
  hasNextPage: boolean;
  endCursor: string;
}

interface Connection<Edge> {
  pageInfo: PageInfo;
  edges: Edge[];
}

interface Response<Node> {
  hasNextPage: boolean;
  endCursor: string;
  nodes: Node[];
}

const extractConnectionInfo = <Edge extends { node?: Node }>({ edges, pageInfo }: Connection<Edge>): Response<Node>  => {
   ...parsing work
}
```

In above code, I cannot infer type of `node`. I receive `unknown[]` as response.

```
// type of nodes is "unknown[]"
const { nodes } = extractConnectionInfo({ edges, pageInfo });
```

Is there a way to infer `node` type from function argument which is nested object? Nested object is `edge` and structure is like below.

```
edge: {
  node: {
    ...properties which are different from other node.
  }
}
```

I can use "type assertion" to inform type of `node` to VSCode, but I wanna infer type from function argument. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do:

```ts
declare const extractConnectionInfo: <
    Edge extends { node?: unknown }
>(data: Connection<Edge>) => Response<Edge['node']>
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mq8GdN)